# Regarding uniform convergence of a series

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Reading a textbook on basic complex analysis I stumbled upon the following result:
The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\tfrac{z^n}{n}$ converges uniformly and absolutely in the closed disk $\overline{D(0,r)}$ but does not converge uniformly on $D(0,1)$.

My question comes with the argument that is used to show that the series indeed does not converge uniformly on $D(0,r)$ which is as follows:

Say it does converge uniformly, then, using Cauchy criteria for uniform convergence, we have that for every $\epsilon>0$ exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. if $n>N$,
$$
\frac{x^n}{n}+\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{x^{n+p}}{n+p}<\epsilon,\quad\forall x\in[0,1),\quad\forall p\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
Now, since the harmonic series diverges, using again Cauchy criteria, we have that
$$
\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{N+p}>2\epsilon.\tag1
$$
Then we have
$$
\frac{x^N}{N}+\frac{x^{N+1}}{N+1}+\cdots+\frac{x^{N+p}}{N+p}>x^{N+p}\left(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{N+p}\right)>2\epsilon\cdotp x^{N+p}.
$$
Now, using the intermediate value theorem we have that there exists $x\in[0,1)$ s.t. $x^{N+p}>1/2$, and for that $x$ we have a contradiction with $(1)$.

And now to my question, the same argument holds for any $r$ s.t. $r>1/2$? Then we would have that the series does not converge in any closed disk $\overline{D(0,r)}$ with $r>1/2$.

Seems to me that I am missing something.

Comment: This is incorrect. $$
\frac{x^N}{N}+\frac{x^{N+1}}{N+1}+\cdots+\frac{x^{N+p}}{N+p}>x^{N+p}\left(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N}+\cdots+\frac{1}{N}\right)
$$

Comment: An easy way of handling uniform convergence: If it is uniformly convergent, then $\sum \frac {(1-\frac 1n)^{n}} {n}$ would converge. But it doesn't.

Comment: Why do you think that the argument holds for any $r, r>\frac{1}{2}$? You need  the ability for $x$ to be arbitrarily close to $1$ as you want $x^{N+p}>1/2$ to be true, where $N+p$ may be a "very big" number, so to speak.

Comment: I see! I was missing that tiny little detail, but quite an important one; still don't quite get why $x$ needs to be arbitrarily close to 1 for $x^{N+p}>1/2$ to hold, but that's a good pointer imo.

Answer (score 1):

First of all we need to prove it is not uniformly convergent on D(0,1) and then
$$
\frac{x^N}{N}+\frac{x^{N+1}}{N+1}+\cdots+\frac{x^{N+p}}{N+p}>x^{N+p}\left(\frac{1}{N}+\frac{1}{N}+\cdots+\frac{1}{N}\right)>2\epsilon\cdotp x^{N+p}.
$$ This may not be true...

I suggest you to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bYfRWN8mhg4&list=PLDzvuf9Uf4FPFRWaMmBWNtbUukooikwBc&index=4

Comment: you can conclude $x^{N+p} < x^n , \forall n  <  N+p$ but $\frac{1}{N} > \frac{1}{N+k} , \forall k \in \mathbf{N}$